# How to fix "TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'"

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm writing codes to accelerate my program using CUDA, but I got a tricky error. I have no idea about it.My environment is OpenCV 4.1.1, python 3.6.
Here is my code.

I define a function to rotate the img,

```
def rotate(img, angle):
    '''
    '''    
    if len(img.shape) == 3:
        (rows, cols, channels) = img.shape
        out_size = (cols, rows, channels)
    else:
        (rows, cols) = img.shape
        out_size = (cols, rows)

    if angle == 0:
        dst = img

    else:
        # img_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
        img_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
        out_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
#         M_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
#         out_size_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
#         border_value_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()

        m = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2, rows/2), angle, 1) 
        img_gpu.upload(img)
#         M_gpu.upload(M)
#         out_size_gpu.upload((12000, 6000))
#         border_value_gpu.upload((0, 0, 0))
        cols_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
        rows_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
        cols_gpu.upload(cols)
        rows_gpu.upload(rows)

        print(type(img))
        print(img.shape)
        (row,col) = img.shape
        print([img_gpu.size()[0],img_gpu.size()[1]])
#         M = np.float32([[1,0,100],[0,1,50]])
#         out=cv2.UMat(out_gpu,(284,284))
        out_gpu = cv2.cuda.warpAffine(img_gpu, m, (col,row))

        dst = out_gpu.download()

    return dst
```

then I call it.

```
img = cv2.imread('../FengZhan/temp.png',0)
img_rotate = rotate(img, -10)
```

it cannot work and has the following error:

```
<ipython-input-48-41cd06952793> in rotate(img, angle)
     36 #         M = np.float32([[1,0,100],[0,1,50]])
     37 #         out=cv2.UMat(out_gpu,(284,284))
---> 38         out_gpu = cv2.cuda.warpAffine(img_gpu, m, (col,row))
     39 
     40         dst = out_gpu.download()

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

I tried to replace img_gpu with cv2.UMat(img_gpu), but it still cannot work.
Anybody help me?

Answer (score 8):

I got this error: `TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'`

code:

```
image = cv2.imread("image_path")
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Simply because the image path was incorrect and I was loading an image which wasn't there. I realize it might not be your case however I hope it may help others who encounter this error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why do you define in the beginning `out_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()`. And in the end you set it again to: `out_gpu = cv2.cuda.warpAffine(img_gpu, m, (col,row))`.

The reason why you get this error may be because of your code `out_gpu = cv2.cuda.warpAffine(img_gpu, m, (col,row))` argument `img_gpu` is supposed to be a string link to an image, yet it is defined previously as `img_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()`. Try to correct this by replacing the line `img_gpu.upload(img)` by `uploaded_img = img_gpu.upload(img)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your image to be numpy array

```
np.array(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be one bug for OpenCV as I issued at [OpenCV cuda bindings for python seem receive wrong param types for `cudawarping/src/warp.cpp` #2393](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2393).

However, even I fix this bug the speed is not satisying (slower than CPU version), if there are some other tricks, maybe we can share with each other.

Good Luck.